# python gTTS RuntimeError: Unable to get language list: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, spyder

**Pre**
I have seen questions about this kind of error , but it was not related with `gTTS`.

I use `gTTS` module.One day,this error suddenly happened.Yes,I have never handled these codes from the time of importing it.Until yesterday,this error didn't happen.

It happened when I excute this code:

**Code**

`sounditems = [i for i in gtts.lang.tts_langs().values()]`

**Error**

`RuntimeError: Unable to get language list: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

```
In [1]: import gtts

In [2]: gtts.lang
Out[2]: <module 'gtts.lang' from 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\gtts\\lang.py'>

In [3]: gtts.lang.tts_langs()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-53b538afe087>", line 1, in <module>
    gtts.lang.tts_langs()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gtts\lang.py", line 41, in tts_langs
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to get language list: %s" % str(e))

RuntimeError: Unable to get language list: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**gTTS version**

[image]

**Editor**

```
In [7]: spyder.version_info
Out[7]: (3, 2, 8)
```

**language**

`python 3.6.5`

**After search**

I investigated in gTTS lang module.I thought it failes to get imformation from Google.Perhaps,it may not be the problem on the client side.

**Added**

After researching the `lang.py` module,I found out the source of error was from its `_fetch_langs()` function & it seems to have failed to execute `soup.find(src=re.compile(JS_FILE))['src']`.

**[image: Print Code]**

**--result**

[image]

--long html code--

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I executed  `cmp` as your suggestion.Certainly,gtts was reinstalled but this error has existed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gTTS 2.0.3` is already released.

I reinstalled gTTS module by following John D. and I updated `lang.py`.

I rewrote my original code from

`gtts.lang.tts_langs()`

to

`gtts.tts.tts_langs()`

I could solve the problem.

This is not the mirrored answer for my question,but I'm very satisfied.
It seems that gtts module can be updated in the future and is under development now.
I have no reason for persisting to `gTTS 2.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading solved it for me, but had to force a reinstall 
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall gtts

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your gTTS module with : "pip3 install -U gTTS" in your virtual environment...

Comment: Normally, with this command, you have to fix it in upgrading gTTS in version 2.0.3 : python -m pip install --upgrade gTTS